# Getting NET::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN error after certificate replacement

Tags: http, ssl, http-headers, browser-cache

I have recently replaced the SSL certificates issued by RapidSSL because Symantec is no longer trusted by Google. But, after replacing the new SSL certificates I'm experiencing a privacy issue from web browsers. Browser indicates following error when I try to access a domain name which was affected by the new SSL certificates. 
NET::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN

So I did research on this error and found out that this error occurs due to the public key pins cache. but further researching on this matter I found out that the public key pin for SSL certificates has not been changed with newly issued certificates. So if we compare the public key pins between certificates prior to replacement and after the replacement both has same BASE64 encoded hash value. Further, I saw that this issue is getting resolved once the browser cache is cleaned. But our clients do not like to clean their browser cache. So we cannot rely on clearing browser cache. Can you please let us know is there any other way where we can overcome this issue?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I use Let't Encrypt SSL for a corporate site and it updates periodically. After each update I get such errors. Even if I remove HPKP header. Is there a way without cache cleaning?

Comment: You don't have to clean whole browser cache. but you can specifically clean the HPKP header. In chrome go to: **chrome://net-internals/#hsts** and clean specific header belong to your domain name

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help. I also found a solution.

For GC:
Follow instructions from this image:
[image: Instructions for GC]

For FF:

1. Close the browser.
2. Open the file "SiteSecurityServiceState.txt" from the profile folder and remove lines with site domain.
3. Open the browser.

I hope this will be useful if someone is confronted with the same situation.